# Recommendations for books/resource to get started with wordpress 3 development (plugins/themes)

Tags: plugins, customization, themes

i am looking for learning resources to get started with wordpress 3 (i'd like to learn the latest) plugin/theme development. i also looked at [Recommendations for an In-Depth WordPress Book?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/recommendations-for-an-in-depth-wordpress-book)

i am looking for recommendations on which book i should get. considering i am looking for something for wordpress 3

- [Professional Wordpress](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470560541) - i am actually reading this because its the newest i can find on amazon and it got 5/5 rating at amazon!
- [Digging into Wordpress (v3)](http://digwp.com/2010/09/version-3/)
- [Build Your Own Wicked WordPress Themes](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/) - i found this on the [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/recommendations-for-an-in-depth-wordpress-book) supposedly this is more advanced
- [WordPress Plugin Development – Beginner’s Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847193595) - also from the other question. but are they for wordpress 3? is there alot of differences in wordpress 2 vs 3? i guess since i am new to wordpress development, its better and less confusing to get a wordpress 3 book?

Comment: I can't find an actual question in your "question."  You seem to ask for recommendations, then list resources you're already considering.  Please revise and restate, or I'd be tempted to close as "Not a real question."

Comment: See this thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/1126#1126

Answer (score 1):

I have "WordPress Plugin Development - Beginner's Guide" and I like it.  It's not overly "beginner", and the learning curve is very smooth.  Unfortunately, it's only WP2.7