# Definitive list of WordPress books

Tags: books

I've been thinking about what other large community wiki post site can benefit from. Questions about books come up all the time and I think it will be beneficial to have one large list to consolidate available literature on WordPress.

Please include:

- **title**
- **author**(s) (preferably with links and cred)
- **topic**(s) covered
- **user level** targeted
- **form** (paper/ebook)
- **pricing** (if applicable)
- **link** to home site (if available)

Please **one book per answer** so it is easier to edit, discuss and vote on.

Please **keep it civil with affiliate links**. I don't particularly mind those, but we all want to see books that are genuinely useful, not those with large commission.

Comment: Nice post!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/recommendations-for-an-in-depth-wordpress-book

Comment: @Grant Palin that question is about advanced books. There had been multiple books questions and there are a lot of duplicate book suggestions between them, that it why I wanted to start comprehensive community wiki list.

Answer (score 8):

## Professional WordPress Plugin Development

By:

- [Brad Williams](http://strangework.com/),  co-author of "Professional WordPress" book
- [Ozh Richard](http://planetozh.com/blog/)
- [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/) of [Theme Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com/) and (formerly) [DevPress](http://devpress.com/)
- (editor) [Andrew Nacin](http://andrewnacin.com/), WordPress core developer

> The trio of established authors
>   provides a practical, solutions-based
>   approach along with a collection of
>   timely examples and plenty of code,
>   all aimed at clearly explaining how to
>   create a plugin file, work with users,
>   integrate widgets, add menus and
>   submenus, secure your plugins, and
>   more.

[image]

**Plugin development** for range from **hobbyists to professionals**.

- [Wrox paper](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development.productCd-0470916222.html), $45
- [Wrox ebook](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development.productCd-1118075307.html) (PDF, social DRM), $45 [-35% with `FROST` discount code](https://twitter.com/#!/ozh/status/43378069972582400)
- [Amazon preorder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470916222), ~$30
- [Kindle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004PGMI2I), $38

[Full table of content](http://planetozh.com/blog/books/professional-wordpress-plugin-development/5/)

Samples (PDF):

- [Excerpt 1](http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/22/04709162/0470916222-179.pdf)
- [Excerpt 2](http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/22/04709162/0470916222-180.pdf)
- [Excerpt 3](http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/22/04709162/0470916222-181.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

## Digging into WordPress

By [Jeff Starr](http://perishablepress.com/) and [Chris Coyier](http://chriscoyier.net/) of [popular WordPress blog by same name](http://digwp.com/).

> From your first steps of learning
>   about WordPress all the way through
>   maintaining a site throughout the
>   years, this book is packed with truly
>   practical information.

[image]
<sub>(source: [digwp.com](http://digwp.com/wp-content/themes/DiggingIntoWordPress-2/images/sidebarbook.png))</sub>

Large solid books that covers **multiple topics** from installation to internals, customization and maintenance. For **wide range of users** from novice to intermediary+. Updated for major WordPress releases (currently contains updates for 2.9 and 3.0).

Available as:

- **paper+PDF** bundle, $70
- **PDF** download, $27

[Sample (PDF)](http://digwp.com/book-demo/Digging-Into-WP-DEMO.pdf).

http://digwp.com/book/

Comment: Great book, but wish it was more like a book and not a giant Powerpoint.

Answer (score 3):

## [Beginning WordPress 3](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228954)

by [Stephanie Leary](http://sillybean.net/id=goIhPPx9jfkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

http://www.apress.com/media/catalog/product/cache/9/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/A/9/A9781430228950-3d_10.png

> Beginning WordPress 3 is a complete guide for the beginning developer who wants to start using WordPress. You'll learn how to publish and manage online content, add media, create widgets and plugins, and much more.

**Level** | Intermediate

That blurb above is spot-on, but this book should probably be called *Beginning WordPress 3 Development*. Reason being, this book is aimed at people who are comfortable with *using* WordPress but want to explore *programming* WordPress. Nice lightweight introduction to core concepts like the plugin/widget APIs, custom post types and taxonomies, basic techniques for slicing and dicing HTML into a theme, etc. A good introduction for someone about to embark on their first theme build, and a great jump point for more advanced books.

**eBook** | $27.99

**Paper** | $39.99

[Book preview is available on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=goIhPPx9jfkC&lpg=PP1&dq=Beginning%20WordPress%203&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

## Build Your Own Wicked WordPress Themes

**authors:** [Allan Cole](http://allancole.com/wordpress/), [Raena Jackson Armitage](http://www.raena.net/), [Brandon R. Jone](http://blog.epicerastudio.com/)s and [Jeffrey Way](http://jeffrey-way.com/)

> We'll simplify your life as a
>   developer by introducing you to the
>   Thematic framework, so that building
>   solid themes is a breeze! You'll also
>   learn how to maximize profits by
>   effectively marketing and selling your
>   themes on the Web's biggest
>   marketplaces.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100831-223240.png))</sub>

**topic(s) covered:** General WordPress overview, theme customization and development

**user level targeted:** adv. beginner/intermediate

**form:** Paperback, MOBI, PDF, EPUB

**pricing:** $40USD, $30USD Digital Bundle

[Table of contents](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/toc.php), [request sample](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/samplechapters.php).

**link to home site:** http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/

No affiliation, just a happy purchaser

Answer (score 2):

## WordPress and Ajax (2nd Edition)

by [Ronald Huereca](http://www.ronalfy.com/)

> The WordPress and Ajax e-book is a
>   comprehensive view on using Ajax with
>   WordPress. The book lays the
>   foundation for you, and then walks you
>   through three real-world examples of
>   how to use Ajax within WordPress.

[image]

Book focuses on **JavaScript, Ajax and jQuery** in WordPress.

Available as:

- [**ebook**](http://www.wpajax.com/download) <del>(price not disclosed without going to PayPal for processing, I didn't bother)</del> had been made free to download
- **paper**, $20

[Sample](http://www.wpajax.com/preview) (not working at time of writing this)

http://www.wpajax.com/

Answer (score 1):

## WordPress User Guide

By [David Coveney](http://davidcoveney.com/), director of [InterconnectIT](http://interconnectit.com/).

> Our WordPress User Guide takes you
>   through the process of setting up a
>   WordPress blog, entering and editing
>   content, managing comments, building
>   menus and so much more.

Book was written as **training manual for novice users** and covers how to operate WordPress-based site. Note that installation and configuration are not covered.

Available as:

- **free PDF download** (for personal use and distribution in free educational establishments)
- **high resolution PDF download**, *£4 incl VAT (Appx $6)*
- **paid .docx download** customizable and rebrandable at price of *£75 incl VAT
  (Appx $120 US)*

http://interconnectit.com/products/wordpress-user-guide/

Answer (score 1):

## WordPress Plugin Development – Beginner’s Guide

By [Vladimir Prelovac](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/), professional WordPress developer.

> The book consists of 8 chapters, six
>   of which are dealing with development
>   of actual plugins from scratch [...]
>   Introductory chapter explains why
>   engage in WordPress plugin development
>   and shows the best tools for the job.
>   Final chapter deals with plugin
>   localization, promotion, providing
>   support and few other handy tips.

[image]

Book that focuses on WordPress **plugin development for programmers**.

Available as:

- **paper**, ~$30-35 via Amazon
- **paper+ebook**, ~$40 via packt

[Table of contents](https://www.packtpub.com/toc/wordpress-plugin-development-beginners-guide-table-contents), [sample chapter (PDF)](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/sample_chapters/wordpress-plugin-development-sample-chapter-2-social-bookmarking_0.pdf).

http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-plugin-development-book

Answer (score 1):

## WordPress Bible

by [Aaron Brazell](http://technosailor.aaronbrazell.com/)

> You'll start with the basics of
>   WordPress, such as the principles of
>   blogging and social media interaction.
>   Then the pace ramps up to more
>   intermediate-to-advanced topics
>   including plugins, WordPress Loop,
>   themes and templates, custom fields,
>   caching, security, and more.

[image]

Large comprehensive reference.

Available as:

- **paper**, $31
- **Kindle**, $30
- preorder 2nd edition, $32

http://technosailor.aaronbrazell.com/the-wordpress-bible/

Answer (score 0):

### Professional WordPress

Design and Development

[image]

By:
Hal Stern (Author)
David Damstra (Author)
Brad Williams (Author)
Mike Little (Technical Editor)

An in-depth look at the internals of the WordPress system. As the most popular blogging and content management platform available today, WordPress is a powerful tool. This exciting book goes beyond the basics and delves into the heart of the WordPress system, offering overviews of the functional aspects of WordPress as well as plug-in and theme development.

[Wrox paper](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-WordPress.productCd-0470560541.html)  $45
[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470560541)     ~$30
Kindle          ~$27